# Constraints in Xcode IB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to understand constraints in IB.  I have three view that I'm trying to set the rules on the location.  (Each view isdescribed in its other xib).

[image: my constraints]

How do I correctly specify these rules?  How do I set constraints without setting the exact height of more than one view?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the exact problem you are having and what is the expected outcome?

Comment: result need: constrains by rules  headerView depends of content H=[0...70], contentView depends of content H=[0...220]. I did like the screenshot, but IB says this constrains has error with heights.

Comment: How do I set constraints, without setting the exact height for more than one view? (two or more view are constraints to less or greater for height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myself answer.
you need for constraints less/greater  **add to low-priority height for aims**.
for example: you need a view in height from 10 to 90 depending on the content inside and as less as possible space in height.
you specify:

- A.1) H <= 90,
- A.2) H> = 10
- A.3) H = 10 @ 250 //  aims to height

If you have multiple view in each subsequent rule in paragraph shall be at #3

- B.3) H = 10 @ 249
- C.3) H = 10 @ 248
  etc

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oUXq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it using proportional heights between the parent (stack view) and the subviews.

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot shows the views' behavior when the xib is small and the second when it is bigger, keeping height of the views 70, 220 and 70 at maximum.

Comment: **Allan**, but why should I equal heights, i need different heights for each view!
headerView depends of content H=[0...70]
contentView depends of content H=[0...220]

and... with margin all clear
but it is not needed as for the example I use stackView (vertical)

Comment: Ok, sorry. If I understand you want to set the heights to the views respectively: 70, 220 and 70 in the stack view right? Add the stack view (the parent view) three constraints, like the first image I posted (but without the equal heights rule). After, for each sub view, add a top margin with constant zero and set a height for each. The stack view will auto adjust it's height depending on the heights you set for each sub view.

Comment: not equal heights 70, 220 and 70. i need heights 0..70, 0..220 and 70. i need for two first views heights **less** or equal 70, heights **less** or equal 220

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but you are evil.
You specify strong height by constrains as a: view.height x 0.25, view.height x 0.5, view.height x 0.25

Comment: What do you mean? These are constraints to make the height proportional, although the height must be limited to a certain value and have higher priority in order not to conflict. Anyway [this WWDC video may help](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-218/). They talk about UIStackView that you're using.